# notifications alerts turn off sql php

Tags: php, sql, left-join

I'm creating a basic notification system to alert an user, that the users he follows have created a new post.

Users

```
  id_user | name
    1       Max
    2       Joe
    3       Ed
    4       Tommy
```

Posts

```
    id_post | id_user_post | posts
    1               2           hi
    2               2           hello
    3               2           how are you
    4               3           hey you
    5               2           how long
    6               1           whats up
    7               2           come on
```

Community

```
  id_follower id_followed
    3           2
    3           1
    4           2
```

In this case Ed (user 3) follows to Joe (2) and Max (1), they both, have posted 6 posts.

```
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM community c
     LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.id_user_post=c.id_followed
   WHERE c.id_follower=3
```

Here is how it looked like in the page

```
  Homepage header
   You have (6 new posts) > [click here to see]
```

My problem is how do I turn off the notification alert (6 new posts) after clicking on the it?
Do I need to create a notifications table? Should I need to add an status field to the post? 
Do I need to make an Sql query again?  Otherwise that notification is going to appear forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `last_post_id` column to the `community` table. Then you can count only the posts whose ID is higher than this.

```
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM community c
     LEFT JOIN posts p ON p.id_user_post=c.id_followed AND p.id_post > c.last_post_id
   WHERE c.id_follower=3
```

Whenever you show the status to a user, you update the `last_post_id` to the highest ID:

```
UPDATE community AS c
JOIN (SELECT id_user_post, MAX(id_post) AS id_post
      FROM posts
      GROUP BY id_user_post) AS p ON p.id_user_post=c.id_followed
SET c.last_post_id = p.id_post
WHERE c.id_follower = 3
```

Comment: Ok, than you. but this is in case I am the only follower of those two users. What happen if 100 users more follow to users 1 & 2. If I update the last id post seen, those users wont see any notifications on their homepage because I'm updating something they are supposed to update.  Am I right?

Comment: Each follower has their own `last_post_id` value. You're only updating the rows where `id_follower = 3`.

Comment: Ya I've understood. You definitely got it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm testing your code, but when I update the query, It store the minimun `p.id_post` in `last_post_id`, I tried to use `max(id_post)` but it doesnt work out

Comment: Yeah, need to use a grouped subquery to get the last post for each id.

Comment: ok, thank you let me try. but in this case, it would be `group by [what column name]?`

Comment: ....`SET c.last_post_id = (SELECT MAX(p.id_post) FROM p GROUP BY p.id_user WHERE p.id_user=c.id_followed)`....I have this but is not working